# when emailing to my aliases using postfix I get the error that the user doesn't exist

Tags: email, alias, postfix

I'm trying to send an email to my aliases in my system. This is how my aliases file look like:

```
cat aliases
users: user, user1
```

After I added the aliases I added it to postfix with `postalias aliases` then I restarted my postfix service and then my dovecot service. I then tried to send an email to my alias with `mutt`:

```
 mutt -s "hello from root" users
```

But the email doesn't get deliver to either user or user1 and I get a email in the mailbox from when I sent the email:

> The mail system
>
> : unknown user: "users"

```
postconf alias_maps alias_database local_recipient_maps
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
local_recipient_maps = proxy:unix:passwd.byname $alias_maps
```

Comment: The mail system error is correct.  See my answer below.

Comment: please edit your post and add the output of `postconf alias_maps alias_database local_recipient_maps`

Comment: postconf output looks OK (i thought comma separator was required at first, but `man 5 postconf` indicates that whitespace or comma is OK - my config has commas, and aliases work without a problem here, so that may be worth trying).    Can you add the mail.log entries for sending a test message to an alias? (hint: grep for the destination address to get the queue-id, and then grep for the queue-id).

Comment: btw, read that man page, search for local_recipient_maps and check the things it mentions: 1. have you change the local delivery agent (MDA) or local transport setting or do you use luser_relay, mailbox_transport, or fallback_transport?  2. have you configured proxymap so that it can access the passwd file.  3. related to that, if you're running postfix chrooted (you probably are unless you've changed the default setup), is the aliases hash db accessible within that chroot?  you may need to use proxy for it it too.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the alias must be set for a user that actually exists.  The user `users` doesn't exist.  Change the alias to this:

```
user: user, user1
```

OR. Add a user named `users`

Note:  the `user` used for the alias must also be repeated to the right of the colon as shown above if you want the aliased user to get a copy of the emails.

Remember to rerun the *newaliases* command or `postalias /path/to/aliases`.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Interesting.  I've confirmed this just now and updated my answer.

Comment: nonsense.  a big part of the point of an email alias is that the alias DOESN'T have to exist as a user on the mail server.   I have dozens and dozens of aliases on my mail server (each one created for a different web site, mailing list, company, or other organisation that wants an email address for me), none of them exist as a user and all look like `alias: cas` or `alias: cas+alias` (to make it easier to process with procmail).

Comment: that's not what @Alxs wrote (*"OR. Add a user named users"*).  and it's not true, either.  an alias can point to a remote email address, or to another alias.  it can also point to a non-existent local user (in which case, will bounce or be rejected).  if an alias has multiple recipients, delivery will be attempted to all of them - and if any don't exist, only they will bounce.

Comment: I agree with cas, what's the point of the alias then? I mean, if I have an alias: `user: user, user1`, how can I send the email just to user without sending it to user1?

Comment: Just so you know, I changed my aliases to `user: user1` then I ran `postalias` restarted the postfix service and when I send the email to user it gets send to user not to user1

Comment: I defer to cas's expertise in helping resolve your issue, however if your question `when emailing to my aliases using postfix I get the error that the user doesn't exist` re. `The mail system    : unknown user: "users"` wasn't correctly answered, you might look at revising your question.